# System.diagnostics logging issue + Wix application name change

Tags: wix, wix3.6, system.diagnostics, tracelistener

In my application i have configured the Trace listener as below

"HelloWorld" is my **AssemblyName** and **Namespace**

```
<system.diagnostics>
<sources>
  <source name="DebugCategory" switchName="DebugSwitch" switchType="System.Diagnostics.SourceSwitch">
    <listeners>
      <remove name="Default"/>
      <!-- Add the listeners below -->
      <add name="LogFile"/>
    </listeners>
  </source>
</sources>
<sharedListeners>
 <add name="Console" type="System.Diagnostics.ConsoleTraceListener" initializeData="true"/>
 <add name="LogFile" type="HelloWorld.Diagnostics.FileLogTraceListener, HelloWorld" initializeData="HelloWorld.log" traceOutputOptions="DateTime" cycle="Month"/>
</sharedListeners>
```

While creating an installer using WIX, in my WIX file i will make the Target exe file from "HelloWorld.exe" to **"MyWorld.exe"** as below

```
  <Component Id="MyWorld.exe" Guid="*">
    <File Id="MyWorld.exe" Name="MyWorld.exe"
        DiskId="1" Source="HelloWorld.exe" />
    <Shortcut Id="HelloWorld.menu.exe" Name="Hello world application" Directory="McnMenu" Advertise="yes" WorkingDirectory="INSTAL32LLOCATION" />
  </Component>
```

Since there is change in the **EXE** name, Tracelistener is not creating a log file.

Target name should be "Myworld.exe", If i revert the File element to

```
     <File Id="HelloWorld.exe" Name="HelloWorld.exe" />
```

it works well

Can any one help me.

Answer (score 1):

In this line of your .config file:

```
<add name="LogFile" type="HelloWorld.Diagnostics.FileLogTraceListener, HelloWorld" initializeData="HelloWorld.log" traceOutputOptions="DateTime" cycle="Month"/>
```

You have `type="HelloWorld.Diagnostics.FileLogTraceListener, HelloWorld"`. That is a reference to a class in an assembly. The assembly name (the name of the file) is the part after the comma. Therefore your .config file requires the assembly (the executable in your case) to be named "HelloWorld".

To fix you can either leave the file name HelloWorld.exe (as you found) or change the .config file like so:

```
<add name="LogFile" type="HelloWorld.Diagnostics.FileLogTraceListener, MyWorld" initializeData="HelloWorld.log" traceOutputOptions="DateTime" cycle="Month"/>
```

Notice the `MyWorld` in the `type` after the comma.

Comment: It seems a hack to me to build a file as one name and deploy it as another.  .NET assemblies are aware of what their filename should be.